# How to prevent Backbone.js routing (or history) to automagically add parameters to GET-request?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, backbone.js

I have a very strange issue here, that I think has got something to do with the Backbone.js routing.

In our mobile app, there is a login-screen, that executes a AJAX-Post-Request (with jQuery), that runs against an API. Username, password and a third parameter are in the POST-body. This works like a charm.

The strange behaviour kicks in, after Backbone.js begins to to do some routing. After re-directing the browser, (only!) the username and password are send as a parameter-list to the GET request.

So the request i.e.

```
http://localhost:3000/#login
```

for unknown reason becomes

```
http://localhost:3000/?username=myuser&password=mypassword#login
```

Please notice, that the new parameters in the GET-request are not 100% part of the POST-body, because the savePassword-parameter is missing. Also notice, that the login-request goes against the API, (/api/user/login), not the route of the login-screen (/#login)

I already tried out a lots of things, also taking all the backbone-sourcecode apart, but still can't find how to prevent this behaviour.

Another notice: I see this only on mobile, so in the UIWebView on iOS and the WebView-object on Android. Maybe this issue is also related to the mobile...

I am very happy for any help, answers or hints, how to disable this behaviour and get the username/password out of this freakin URL.

**Edited:**
This is the AJAX-Request for loggin in.

```
login: function(username, password, savePassword, successcallback, errorcallback) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: config.api_base_url + 'user/login',
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            savePassword: savePassword
        },
        success: function(data, response, xhr) {
            app.auth_token = xhr.getResponseHeader('Authtoken');
            $.cookie('auth_token', app.auth_token);
            if (successcallback) {
                successcallback();
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            if (errorcallback) {
                errorcallback(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the  AJAX-Post-Request (with jQuery)?

Comment: Edited the question with the ajax-code.

Comment: as another option you can use jQuery.post() https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) docs:

> **data**
>
> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

And than, you should add in your settings `processData` equal to false:

> **processData** (default: true)
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

Code jQuery.ajax():

```
login: function(username, password, savePassword, successcallback, errorcallback) {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: config.api_base_url + 'user/login',
        data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
            savePassword: savePassword
        },
        processData: false,
        success: function(data, response, xhr) {
            app.auth_token = xhr.getResponseHeader('Authtoken');
            $.cookie('auth_token', app.auth_token);
            if (successcallback) {
                successcallback();
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            if (errorcallback) {
                errorcallback(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Made me understand jQuery a little bit better. But unfortunately this didn't solved my problems. But I am getting closer, seems, that every request after the Login is interpreted as a form-submit-request (I guess by some internal routing). And then this name-magic from the input-fields are putting the parameters in the URL. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: That specific example is a form with `method="get"`.. You should be using `method="post"` instead

Comment: We use an ajax-based POST in the submit of the form with JavaScript. But my guess is, that subsequent request, that are triggered by the routing, are interpreted as form-submit requests, and this seems to where the GET comes into play.